# Migrate(copy) ACR with tag using Import-AzContainerRegistry

Tags: powershell, acr

I am trying to import Azure container registry with tags.

I know the Azure cli command:
  `az acr import --name $TARGET_REG --source $SOURCE_REG.azurecr.io/$repo":"$tag;`

But Azure cli doesn't support in my work station and need to transform it into Power shell something like:

`Import-AzContainerRegistryImage -RegistryName $TARGET_REG -ResourceGroupName $RG_NAME -SourceRegistryUri $SOURCE_REG_URI -SourceImage $tag`

Any guidance over there?

Comment: So the power shell command is wrong and you need someone to correct it? Please be more specific about what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to transform my command from Azure cli to Azure Power shell module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of trials and errors I am able to transform it with the below line of code that worked for me:

```
Import-AzContainerRegistryImage -RegistryName $TARGET_REG -ResourceGroupName $TARGET_RG_NAME -SourceRegistryResourceId $SOURCE_REG_RES_ID -SourceImage $repo:$tag
```